# Contact Form Example Stuck

Tags: asp.net, web

I designed a Contact.aspx web page but I get an error on "Submit" button.When I run Contact.aspx ı get an error like this:

Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.contact_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Button1_Click' and no extension method 'Button1_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.contact_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

```
 </table> </div> <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="Button1_Click" /> </form>
```

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Where is your `Button1_Click` method located?

Comment: The error is actually quite clear: `'ASP.contact_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Button1_Click' and no extension method 'Button1_Click'`. As mentioned by others: make sure there's a Button1_Click method.

Comment: yeah you are right I made protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) I have name+e-mail+CompanyName+Sector textBox that user should fill boxs  and I have 1 dropdownlist also.How can I get these values from textboxes and dropwdownlist and also How can I apply in my Button1_Click method.

Answer (score 0):

Check `Contact.aspx.cs` Code file & does it contain `Button1_Click` method implementation. If not, implement it.